# how to get values of dynamically generated textbox and send to php file through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a php while loop which fetches products from that database and generates textboxs according to the database values. i want to send the values of the dynamically generated textbox to an external php whenever a specific textbox is clicked using ajax function.

php to fetch data from database and create dynamic textbox

```
while($row =$query->fetch()){
$emma =$row['meal_id'];
$emm =$row['meal_name'];
$ema ='buttion_'.$emma;
?>
<li style="list-style:none;display:inline-block"><input type="text" id="myid[]"name="myid[]" value="<?php echo $emm;?>"style="background:red;border:none;border-radius:5px;margin:2px;height:50px;color:white;" onclick="return getttvalues();" readonly></li>
<?php

}
```

jquery function to send data to php external file when a textbox is clicked

```
function getttvalues(){
    var studentid = document.getElementById('myid[]').value;
    var datastring = 'studentid='+studentid;
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"getgroup_code.php",
        data:datastring,
        dataType:'Text',
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){

            var result = JSON.parse(html);
             $("#name").val(result[1]);
        }

    });
    return false;


}
```

i have tried but for some crazy reason whenever i click a textbox its only the value of one textbox being seen and its not changing even if i click another textbox

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the ID attribute. In order to get all the fields, look for the field by class.

and to get the value of the immeno active field on which the action came, use "this"

```
var studentid = document.getElementById(this).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a specific ID for your text boxes and remove the onclick argument:
then you can create event listeners by clicking on them

```
<?php

$buttons = '';
$rows = [
    [
        'meal_id'   => 1,
        'meal_name' => 'text1 text1 text1'
    ],
    [
        'meal_id'   => 2,
        'meal_name' => 'text2 text2 text2'
    ],
    [
        'meal_id'   => 3,
        'meal_name' => 'text3 text3 text3'
    ]
];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $emma = $row['meal_id'];
    $emm  = $row['meal_name'];
    $ema  = 'buttion_' . $emma;

    $buttons .= '<li style="list-style:none;display:inline-block">
        <input type="button" id="'.$ema.'" name="something" value="'.$emm.' "style="background:gray;border:none;border-radius:5px;margin:2px;height:50px;color:white;" readonly>
        </li>';
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php echo $buttons; ?>
</ul>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#buttion_1").click(function(e) {
            console.log('button 1 was clicked: ' + $(e.target).attr("id"));
            getttvalues($(e.target).attr("id"));
        });
        $("#buttion_2").click(function(e) {
            console.log('button 2 was clicked: ' + $(e.target).attr("id"));
            getttvalues($(e.target).attr("id"));
        });
        $("#buttion_3").click(function(e) {
            console.log('button 3 was clicked: ' + $(e.target).attr("id"));
            getttvalues($(e.target).attr("id"));
        });
    });

    function getttvalues(studentid) {
        var datastring = 'studentid=' + studentid;
        console.log('ajax will be called: ' + studentid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getgroup_code.php",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: 'Text',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                console.log('ajax ran successfully. do whatever you want');
            }

        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i treid this but still not working <input id="<?php $ema ;?>">

Comment: i have tried both your methods but i get no action. not even an error.i have tried giving array ID like id="myid[]". then using indexof to get the index of the clicked id my i only get the -1 alert. kindly help with more solutions or maybe am doing in wrong. can i echo a php id varible in javascript?? something like this;var imageList=document.getElementById('<?php echo $idvariable;?>').value;

Comment: I can't test your code, because I don't have your database. But my code above works (I changed a little bit again). It renders 3 gray buttons and when you click on them, the function with the ajax code will be called.
Just create a php file, copy-paste into it and run. You should check and understand how it works then you can replace step by step my code with your. Once it doesn't work, you have to step back and try it again.

Comment: if you want to test the values in your javascript code, you have to use your browsers web developer tool bar. put console.log(studentid); in your javascript and it will display its value on the console panel

Comment: new test code extended with console.log() https://www.tehplayground.com/fnBAWF8jCa3a3RfI

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few different ways to approach this.  Either going the inline binding route you are doing, or using a delegate binding.  Personally I would suggest the delegate binding approach, but I'll show both approaches.

**Delegate Binding**

When you generate your element, give them all a shared class. (I've removed most of your styling to make it smaller for the example)

```
<li><input type="text" name="myid[]" value="" class="studentid" readonly></li>
```

Then you can create a delegate binding for the element so that it will process the click event for any of the elements that exist now or are created in the future.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.studentid', function(){
    var studentid = this.value;

    ...the rest of your code...
});
```

**Inline Binding**

The same thing can be done with an inline binding if you provide the method with the element that was clicked.

```
<li><input type="text" name="myid[]" value="" onclick="getvalues(this);" readonly></li>
```

Then your method is changed to accept in the element passed to it.

```
function getvalues (student) {
    var studentid = student.value;

    ...the rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: i have tried both your methods but i get no action. not even an error.i have tried giving array ID like id="myid[]". then using indexof to get the index of the clicked id my i only get the -1 alert. kindly help with more solutions or maybe am doing in wrong. can i echo a php id varible in javascript?? something like this;var imageList=document.getElementById('<?php  echo $idvariable;?>').value;

Comment: Neither of these suggestions use an id.  The first one uses a `class`.